# Enviar dados de um input para outra página e mostrar automaticamente com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Gostaria que ao clicar no botão enviar os dados de um input fosse apresentado em outra tela de forma automática.

Ex: Página 1
Escrevo: Maria e clico em enviar

Página 2: recebo a Maria e mostro na tela sem precisar de ação nenhuma.

Sei fazer somente na mesma tela, dando um alerta:

```
<input id="textinput" name="textinput" value="" type="text">
<button onclick="enviar()">Enviar</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function enviar(){
        var valor = document.getElementById("textinput").value;
        alert("Você digitou: " + valor);
    }
   </script>
```

Gostaria de fazer isso sem redirecionar a tela, duas páginas destintas mesmo, como se a página 2 tivesse monitorando a primeira.

Comment: Seria em tempo real?? Se sim, podes usar websocket (ou equivalente)

Comment: Sim, em tempo real! Vou pesquisar!